# How to transfer data between Views in a Layout

Tags: java, android, view

I haven't beeen able to find the answer to the following question:

How do I get data from View A to View B, with View A and View B in the same LinearLayout? Is this even possible? Do I need to start working with threads?

I haven't been able to get the correct search phrase I guess, I'm probably not the first person that wants to do this, but I can't find it :(

Below is what I use now to create the views. In the TargetTrainer (which extends View) I'm letting the user give some input, and I'd like to be able to give feedback to the user in the TextView. How would I for instance show the coordinates of the onTouchEvent of TargetTrainer in the TextView?

Below is a clipped/simplified version of my program.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    LinearLayout linear;
    linear = new LinearLayout(this);

    linear.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    TextView text = new TextView(this);
    text.setText("Test");
    linear.addView(text);

    Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay(); 
    int width = display.getWidth();
    int height = display.getHeight();

    TargetTrainer t = new TargetTrainer(this, width, height);
    linear.addView(t);
    setContentView(linear);

}
```

Comment: I Think I might need to do something with a Context perhaps, as we need to pass that to a View, but that's pretty unclear to me as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should set the id of that TextView, listen to the touch events in your TargetTrainer, and when one occures, you use

```
final TextView tv = (TextView)TargetTrainer.this.findViewById(R.id.myTextView);
tv.setText(touchEvent.toString());
```

That's it.

**Update**

It would be much cleaner, if you'd build your main layout from an xml source.
You need to create a new layout xml inside the /res/layout that looks like the one you're creating inside your `onCreate` method:

**res/layout/main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <TextView android:id="@+id/myTextView" android:text="Test"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <!-- change the your.package part to match the package declaration 
        of your TargetTrainer class -->
    <your.package.TargetTrainer android:id="@+id/myTargetTrainer"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
```

This way a new entry will be placed inside your R class' static `layout` class with the name `main`.
You can reference it by `R.layout.main`.

Note, that in this xml you have id attributes defined for both

- your TextView: `myTextView`, and
- your TargetTrainer:
  'myTargetTrainer'.

The @+id inside the xml tag means that you are creating a new id with the name after the '/' sign.
This also will create new members inside your R class' static `id` class with the names you've provided: `myTextView` and `myTargetTrainer` that are accessible from now on from anywhere in your code.

If you've built this xml, your `onCreate` method will look like this:

```
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    // attach the OnTouchListener to your TargetTrainer view:
    (TargetTrainer)findViewById(R.id.myTargetTrainer).setOnTouchListener(this);
}
```

You also have to extend your main activity class to implement the `View.OnTouchListener` interface, and add the necessary method at the end of your class:

```
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event)
{
    //note, that here the view parameter is the view the touch event has been dispatched to
    final TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.myTextView);
    tv.setText(event.toString());
    return true; //or false, if you are dealing further with this event in parent classes
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Not working for me yet though. I can manually set the ID by just assigning a number right? I'm not quite getting the R.layout.textview part. Anyway if I assign a random number (6564) to the textview, and put 

final TextView tv = (TextView)TargetTrainer.this.findViewById(6564);

I get a nullpointerexception at tv.setText(touchEvent.toString());
(It's not the rouchevent: tv.setText("test"); fails as well)

Comment: i'll update in answer in a few minutes, and share a clean sample for R and layout usage.

Comment: I'm using what you said now, I'm getting along in understanding how this stuff works and it makes much more sense, it's cleaner like you said. I got all my layout done in xml now and that's a lot better! Main issue was passing the width and height of the screen to the TargetTrainer, but using what Youri taught me I now do this: mTrainingMode = (TrainingMode)context;
  Display display = mTrainingMode.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay
And from there I can get the screen width and height again which I need to size a drawable

Answer (score 1):

As I can see from the snippet, you already pass Context in the constructor `new TargetTrainer(this, width, height)`. Assuming that the code you provided is from activity called `BaseActivity` create reference to `BaseActivity` in the `TargetTrainer` constructor and call the update method from `TargetTrainer`.

```
public TargetTrainer extends View {

    ....
    BaseActivity mBaseActivity = null;


    public MyView(Context context, int width, int height) {
    ....
    mBaseActivity = (BaseACtivity)context;
    ....        
    }

    ....

    private void update(String text)
    {
        mBaseActivity.updateTextView(text);
    }
}
```

In `BaseActivity` create `updateTextView`:

```
public void updateTextView(String updateText){ 
    text.setText(updateText);
}
```

Comment: Yay, that worked! I had a hunch that the whole context stuff was good for something but didn't know what :) This is my first time doing an UI, I'm used to dumping input/output to files - plenty of stuff to learn ;)